# what is size, in bytes, of .NET UWP MediaFrameReference frame

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

In the Microsoft sample project CameraFrames, what is the frame size read by private void Reader_FrameArrived()?

Here's code from the sample project:

```
private void Reader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    // TryAcquireLatestFrame will return the latest frame that has not yet been acquired.
    // This can return null if there is no such frame, or if the reader is not in the
    // "Started" state. The latter can occur if a FrameArrived event was in flight
    // when the reader was stopped.
    using (var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
    {
        _frameRenderer.ProcessFrame(frame);
    }
}
```

What is 'frame' size in bytes?

Comment: Are you expecting there to be a single answer, or are you asking how you discover this number through code?

Comment: Through code, such as answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Media​Frame​Reference.Buffer​Media​Frame.Buffer.Length`.

```
using (var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
{
    var length = frame.Buffer​Media​Frame.Buffer.Length;
    _frameRenderer.ProcessFrame(frame);
}
```

I test this on my laptop, the value is 1228800 (the video frame is 640x480, and 4 bytes per pixel).